# How do I correct this method

Tags: javascript

So this is my code (I am learning JS).
I have a method defined in my object.
So for my displayCar() function I have it (what I thought) execute the method.
So when it prints out the details of my generated "cars" I was expecting the method to get printed out as each car detail is printed out.
But it doesn't do that.
It only fires that method one time at the end of the script, no other time.
So I am guessing for whatever reason, the method is not being fired, even though I thought it would be.
Any insight would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you

```
for (var i=0; i < 5; i++)
{
   var carToSell = makeCar();
   displayCar(carToSell);   
}


function makeCar()
{
  var makes = ["Chevy", "GM", "Fiat", "Ford", "Buick", "Toyota", "Nissan", "Honda", "Dodge", "Chrysler"];
  var models = ["Tahoe", "Tacoma", "4Runner", "Insight", "LeSabre", "350Z", "Passport", "Denali", "Charger", "F150"];
  var years = [1955, 2022, 1997, 1985, 1965, 1977, 2019, 2010, 2003, 1945];
  var colors = ["red", "blue", "green", "brown", "seafoam green", "yellow", "orange", "black"];
  var convertible = [true, false];
  
  var rand1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * makes.length);
  var rand2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * models.length);
  var rand3 = Math.floor(Math.random() * years.length);
  var rand4 = Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length);
  var rand5 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5) + 1;
  var rand6 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2);
  var rand7 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 300000);
  
  var car =
  {
    make: makes[rand1],
    model: models[rand2],
    year: years[rand3],
    color: colors[rand4],
    passengers: rand5,
    convertible: convertible[rand6],
    mileage: rand7,
    started: false,
    start: function() 
      {
        this.started = true;
      },
    stop: function() 
      {
        this.started = false;
      },
      
    drive: function() 
      {
        if (this.started)
          {
            document.write("Zoom, Zoom!!");
          }
        else
          {
            document.write("You need to start the engine first.");
          }
       }
  };
  return car;
}

function displayCar(car)
{
  document.write("Your new car is a " + car.year + " " + car.make + " " + car.model + "<br>");
  document.write("The mileage is " + car.mileage + " " + "the color is " + car.color + " and can hold " + car.passengers + " passengers.<br><br>");
  car.drive();
}
```

Comment: Do you mean the drive method is only getting fired at the end?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume the method you are saying is not being called is `drive()`? If so it is getting called it's just printing on the same line as the following car information. Add some line breaks in your `drive` method and it will become more obvious that it is printing. Better yet make each of your printed statements a `<p>` tag.

See below:

```js
for (var i=0; i < 5; i++)
{
   var carToSell = makeCar();
   displayCar(carToSell);   
}


function makeCar()
{
  var makes = ["Chevy", "GM", "Fiat", "Ford", "Buick", "Toyota", "Nissan", "Honda", "Dodge", "Chrysler"];
  var models = ["Tahoe", "Tacoma", "4Runner", "Insight", "LeSabre", "350Z", "Passport", "Denali", "Charger", "F150"];
  var years = [1955, 2022, 1997, 1985, 1965, 1977, 2019, 2010, 2003, 1945];
  var colors = ["red", "blue", "green", "brown", "seafoam green", "yellow", "orange", "black"];
  var convertible = [true, false];
  
  var rand1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * makes.length);
  var rand2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * models.length);
  var rand3 = Math.floor(Math.random() * years.length);
  var rand4 = Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length);
  var rand5 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5) + 1;
  var rand6 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2);
  var rand7 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 300000);
  
  var car =
  {
    make: makes[rand1],
    model: models[rand2],
    year: years[rand3],
    color: colors[rand4],
    passengers: rand5,
    convertible: convertible[rand6],
    mileage: rand7,
    started: false,
    start: function() 
      {
        this.started = true;
      },
    stop: function() 
      {
        this.started = false;
      },
      
    drive: function() 
      {
        if (this.started)
          {
            document.write("Zoom, Zoom!!");
          }
        else
          {
            document.write("<p>You need to start the engine first.</p>");
          }
       }
  };
  return car;
}

function displayCar(car)
{
  document.write("<p>Your new car is a " + car.year + " " + car.make + " " + car.model + "</p>");
  document.write("<p>The mileage is " + car.mileage + " " + "the color is " + car.color + " and can hold " + car.passengers + " passengers.</p>");
  car.drive();
}
```

Comment: Yes at the end where I have car.drive();
I would expect it to be fired and print out something each time the displayCar() runs,
But it doesn't
If you run that code, it will print out all the cars that are generated.
But car.drive(); is only printed out 1 time.  And that is after all the cars that were generated are printed out.

Comment: Ok, I used the <p></p> as suggested, that does seem to work
Can you explain why though?

Comment: So I added in some <p></p> and the formatting looks better and grouped together how I wanted it
document.write("<br>You need to start the engine first.<br><p></p>");

document.write("Your new car is a " + car.year + " " + car.make + " " + car.model + "<br>");

document.write("The mileage is " + car.mileage + " " + "the color is " + car.color + " and can hold " + car.passengers + " passengers.");

car.drive();

Comment: The explanation to why this fixes it is that in your original code it *is* printing every time but it is on the same line as the next car information sentence so it blends in and you're not noticing it.

Comment: Oh duh....I feel like an idiot.
Thank you for your assistance with this.  I appreciate it.
Gotta take time to read things I guess.